# append a piece of text to user's input before determining it's intent by Watson assistant engine

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to append a piece of text to user's input before determining it's intent by Watson assistant engine

for example:

- set context variable $subject = "VPN"
- user input : "I want to set it up"
- add context variable to the input so it becomes : 
  "I want to set it up $subject" ------> "I want to set it up VPN"
- then after doing that watson determines which intent this input belongs to

PS: it doesn't have to be a context variable, I can append some static text

Comment: Better is to capture the intent "set something up" and to know about the context, e.g. VPN or router or coffee maker

Comment: Yes, that feels more natural, but the thing is i have lot's of training examples for setting up the VPN, so i created an intent with these examples and it's working fine for most of the cases. but the issue occurs when user refer to the object in question with "it"

Comment: Then retrain Watson Assistant either to interpret "it" as VPN (you can correct wrong interpretations) or to use the training data for an intent "set something up". Don't make bad decision only because you have data only for that...

Comment: "it" wont refer always to VPN, I will weight things up and do the trade off between using user examples and redesign the assistant.
but can you think of a way to append text to user input?
anyways thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to split this problem up into **intent** and **entities**.

- What is the desired action, the intent? Set something up.
- What is the object / subject involved, the entity? A VPN, a computer.

That way your chatbot is more flexible and can be extended later on.

If you are already talking about VPN in a dialog, you may branch into a VPN-specific set of dialog nodes.

Comment: To follow on with what Henrik said about using both the intent and entities. You can use both in your training questions ( see documentation). 

You can also set up your dialog nodes with the condition only being true when a user says both the intent and entity:VPN or intent and entity:router etc. In fact if you use the intent as the condition to a folder, all the nodes below it would just need to contain the entity as their condition.

Comment: May be I didn't phrase my problem properly, so imagine this scenario:

-Chatbot:shows some options like VPN problems, Email problems etc...
-user: chooses VPN
-Chatbot: what problem do you have with your VPN
-user: I want to set it up
-Chatbot: I don't understand please try rephrasing


the problem arises when users refer to previously mentioned entities with pronouns like "it"